# $X_r$ is the number of cycles of length $r$ in a random permutation of $n$ elements.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics

$X_r$ is the number of cycles of length $r$ in a random permutation of $n$ elements. Find $EX_r, DX_r$.

I tried to find $EX_r$ and get it = $\frac{1}{r}$.

$DX_r = E(X_r^2) - (EX)^2$. How can i find $E(X_r^2)$?

Comment: You should add some information on the question. Are you sampling them uniformly? How did you get $\mathbb{E}[X_r]=\frac{1}{r}$? This will help people when trying to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using combinatorial classes we have the following class $\mathcal{P}$
of permutations with cycles of length $r$ marked:

$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}
\mathcal{P} = \textsc{SET}(
\textsc{CYC}_{=1}(\mathcal{Z})  + \cdots
+ \textsc{CYC}_{=r-1}(\mathcal{Z})
+ \mathcal{U}\times  \textsc{CYC}_{=r}(\mathcal{Z})
+ \textsc{CYC}_{=r+1}(\mathcal{Z})
+ \cdots).$$

This gives the EGF

$$G(z, u) = \exp\left(z+\frac{z^2}{2}
+ \cdots
+ \frac{z^{r-1}}{r-1}
+ u \frac{z^r}{r}
+ \frac{z^{r+1}}{r+1}
+ \cdots \right)
\\ = \exp\left(\log\frac{1}{1-z} + (u-1)\frac{z^r}{r}\right)
= \frac{1}{1-z} \exp\left((u-1)\frac{z^r}{r}\right)
\\ = \frac{1}{1-z} \exp\left(-\frac{z^r}{r}\right)
\exp\left(u\frac{z^r}{r}\right).$$

We have

$$\mathrm{E}[X_r] =
[z^n] \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial u} G(z,u) \right|_{u=1}
\\ = [z^n] \frac{1}{1-z} \exp\left(-\frac{z^r}{r}\right)
\exp\left(\frac{z^r}{r}\right)
\frac{z^r}{r}
= [z^{n-r}] \frac{1}{r} \frac{1}{1-z}
= \frac{1}{r}$$

where $r\le n.$ We also get

$$\mathrm{E}[X_r (X_r-1)] =
[z^n] \left.
\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\right)^2 G(z,u) \right|_{u=1}
\\ = [z^n] \frac{1}{1-z} \exp\left(-\frac{z^r}{r}\right)
\exp\left(\frac{z^r}{r}\right)
\frac{z^r}{r} \frac{z^r}{r}
= [z^{n-2r}] \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{1}{1-z}
= \frac{1}{r^2}$$

where $2r\le n$ and zero otherwise. This is because when $2r\gt n$ we
must have for a given permutation that $X_r = 0$ or $X_r = 1$ so that $X_
r (X_r-1) = 0.$

We obtain at last

$$\mathrm{Var}[X_r] =
\mathrm{E}[X_r (X_r-1)] + \mathrm{E}[X_r] - \mathrm{E}[X_r]^2
\\ = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{r^2} + \frac{1}{r} - \frac{1}{r^2} = \frac{1}{r}
\quad\text{when}\quad 2r\le n \\
\frac{1}{r} - \frac{1}{r^2} = \frac{r-1}{r^2}
\quad\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}.$$